# Float16 Compilation Issues On macOS

Tags: swift, macos

So I'm swiftly coding away, using Float16's left and right. Everything works when I test builds.

Then I decided to test a release build to see how performance is doing. Suddenly, I get `'Float16' is unavailable in macOS` - wut. I've been compiling this all along and it's been working great while in debug mode...

Okay, so I look and see that support was initially added in macOS 11 and iOS 14. I'll mark it conditionally available in these OSes, even though I'm already targeting more recent than that `@available(macOS 11.0, iOS 14.0, *)`. It's really weird that I need do that... aaand it still doesn't work?!

Seriously, wtf is happening here.

I google. I get a bunch of posts about Float16 being added to Swift around 2020, and some stuff about some x86 complications, but that was a couple years ago and it says it's supported in macOS 11, so it must be resolved by n-....

Comment: This is more of a rant than a question. Could you rewrite it somewhat so it has a clearly formulated question, I know you have already answered it yourself but to be helpful to others you should improve the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But no - it's NOT resolved for x86! I ran into this issue several times before I finally noticed the docs say the following:

> A half-precision (16b), floating-point value type.
> ***`Float16` is available on Apple silicon, and unavailable on Intel when targeting macOS.***

(emphasis mine)

I know I didn't mention in the above question, but I even tried setting the build settings to only build for the current arch, but that didn't resolve the issue for me (probably because the Float16 is in a Swift Package, which appears to be compiled as a fat x86/arm binary, even if your Xcode build settings are set for current arch only).

However, it's a clumsy fix, but for my purposes, it works to just do

```swift
    #if arch(arm64)
    @available(macOS 11.0, iOS 14.0, *)
    let value: Float16 = 0
    #endif
```

And also noteworthy, but not 100% related to the question, but also from the docs:

> Float80 is available on Intel when the target system supports an 80-bit long double type, and unavailable on Apple silicon.